# matplotlib Boxplot drawer function stats mean

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mean

`Boxplot drawer function` at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html has the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

# fake data
np.random.seed(19680801)
data = np.random.lognormal(size=(37, 4), mean=1.5, sigma=1.75)
labels = list('ABCD')

# compute the boxplot stats
stats = cbook.boxplot_stats(data, labels=labels, bootstrap=10000)

for n in range(len(stats)):
    stats[n]['med'] = np.median(data)
    stats[n]['mean'] *= 2

print(list(stats[0]))
```

There is a line of code `stats[n]['mean'] *= 2` within the `for loop` that I can't understand. Is it wrong or does it mean something?

Comment: The comment above that line in the example says: *"I'll set the median of each set to the median of all the data, and double the means"*; so this is just to show that you can arbitrarily alter the statistics. Mathematically it is of course unsound to do that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you! I looked at the code only.